# Pick an icon form icon pack for website

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, icons

I have a bunch of icons/images in *one* file.  I am trying to pick some icons from that file instead of slicing the file into smaller image files.

Is there a way to show a specific icon from an entire file without creating multiple smaller image files - perhaps using either javascript or css?  Thanks.

P.S:  This is NOT for any mobile platform, and this is going to be a one or two times thing -- so I am trying to avoid installing any other app (native or otherwise) to do this small project.

Comment: Yes, you can do this . It´s call sprite.. try this -  background: url(yourimage.png) no-repeat 100px 10px; and set a width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css sprite for your icon, this requires all the icons to be in 1 image file, you can then mask the rest of the image by using a background with specific width and height

```
img.home{
 width:46px;
 height:44px;
 background:url(img_navsprites.gif) 0 0;
}
```

you can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 1):

[Mozzilla developer Network on sprites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Image_Sprites)

This can be done using regular CSS:

```
div {
  height: Npx; /*Height of the part of the sprite sheet*/
  width: Npx; /*Width of the part of the sprite sheet*/
  background:url(sprite.png); /*The file path of the sprite sheet*/
  background-position:Npx Npx; /*The position of the sprite*/
}
```

`N` refers to a number only you will know.

With `background-position`, the first argument is the `Y` axis (up and down) and the second is the `x` axis (left and right).

You can shorten it down to be:

```
background:url(sprite.png) Npx Npx;
```

If you want to set the height slightly bigger than the sprite you can do some other tricks like:

```
background-position:100%;
```

or just use

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this site out: http://spritegen.website-performance.org/
it's an online sprite generator, just upload your image, mark the regions inside and download the generated css.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This method called "CSS Sprites" you just need to set URL for your image and set background-position of your icon in image.

**CSS**

```
.your-block {
    background:url(icon-pack.png) 0 0;
}
```

Where "0" "0" your background position coordinates in this image. To have this coordinates you can visit http://www.spritecow.com/ - it is simple service for creating CSS for sprites